# Animation on Splash screen logo image

Tags: java, android, xml, hybrid-mobile-app

I want animation on my logo image like it goes up like slide up animation and as it goes out to activity show on next activity's screen but with small size. my question is what should I do with image pass to intent to next activity and then apply slide up animation or something else .plz answer(animation like a wind up animation in adobe xd)

Comment: https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/shared-element-transition

Comment: i am giving you the idea bhai jaan. you have to customize it according to your need..

Comment: it works for me but there is a little problem, the screen fluctuates(blinks) before animation starts. any suggestions??